# How to plot the loss surface after linear regression using gradient descent?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression

I finished Linear Regression through Gradient Descent like the code below:

```
# Making the imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 9.0)

# Preprocessing Input data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = data.iloc[:, 0]
Y = data.iloc[:, 1]
plt.scatter(X, Y)
# Building the model
m = 0
c = 0

L = 0.0001  # The learning Rate
epochs = 1000  # The number of iterations to perform gradient descent

n = float(len(X)) # Number of elements in X

# Performing Gradient Descent 
for i in range(epochs): 
    Y_pred = m*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
    D_m = (-2/n) * sum(X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt m
    D_c = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
    m = m - L * D_m  # Update m
    c = c - L * D_c  # Update c
    
print (m, c)

# Making predictions
Y_pred = m*X + c

plt.scatter(X, Y) 
plt.plot([min(X), max(X)], [min(Y_pred), max(Y_pred)], color='red')  # regression line
plt.show()
```

Through this code I found best slope `m` and intercept `c`.

Now I want to plot loss surface like this picture.

[image]

I want my loss surface to have X axis as slope, Y axis as intercept and Z axis as Loss function.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use this code snippet:

```py
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
ax.set_title('surface');
```

Comment: I can't understand because I have to save every x,y,z in every iteration(epoch). Could you give me more help? I have hard time implementing ax.plot.surface in my code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).